# RESTEasy: @Form deserialization issue in a @POST method

Tags: json, post, jackson, resteasy

Here's a puzzle!
In a simple POST implementation:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response promote(@Form PromotionForm promotion) {
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
               .entity(promotion.toString())
               .build();
}
```

the argument passed to me does not have values set:

```
PromotionForm{name='null', csid=null}
```

But in debugger I can see that the request server received has the values in its input stream:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
((HttpServletInputMessage) request).getInputStream())).readLine()
// returns: {"name":"form","csid":123}
```

After some debugging I could see that RESTEasy tries to derive arguments for the POST method call:

```
args[i++] = extractor.inject(input, response);
```

Which leads to FormInjector code:

```
propertyInjector.inject(request, response, target);
```

And eventually to FormParamInjector:

```
List<String> list = request.getDecodedFormParameters().get(paramName);
```

But request.getDecodedFormParameters() size is 0. RESTeasy does not try to read
anything from the requests' input stream for some reason.

Any ideas how I can make RESTeasy populate PromotionForm object correctly?

More information below.

### Thanks for all you answers and comments in advance.

The client call is:

```
    final PromotionForm form = new PromotionForm();
    form.setName("form");
    form.setCsid(123L);
    final Response response = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .disableTrustManager()
            .build()
            .target(targetField.getValue())
            .request(requestField.getValue())
            .cookie(cookieNameField.getValue(), cookieValueField.getValue())
            .buildPost(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))
            .invoke();
```

The PromotionForm:

```
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;

public class PromotionForm {
  @FormParam("name")
  private String name;
  @FormParam("csid")
  private Long csid;

  // setters & getters omitted
```

Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
       <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
       <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- scannotation & resteasy-client ommitted -->
```

web.xml snippet:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <!--If the url-pattern for the Resteasy servlet-mapping is not /*-->
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method says that it consumes `application/json`. But the `PromotionForm`-class has `@FormParam`-annotations, which as the name implies, [consumes form data](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_FormParam.html).

To fix this, do one of the following:

Try to post form data instead of json. And change your `@Consumes`-annotation value to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

OR

Remove the `@Form`-annotation. Add JAXB-annotations on `PromotionForm`, so that the json data you post can be mapped to the `PromotionForm`-class.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, JAXB-annotation appears not to be necessary in this case. I guess Jackson can use simple POJO beans.

Comment: @eiden, I wish you new how thankful I am for your answer! 2 days of debugging....